# Better word for "tuition" for summer camp

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word (in American English) to use to describe the payment rendered to a summer camp. The closest word I can think of is the word "tuition" which (in AmE) refers to payment to a school, but that word doesn't seem to be used much for summer camp.

From Google's edition of the Oxford dictionary, I see that this word originally comes from a meaning of "custody, care" in late Middle English (and before that French and Latin) which would seem to be a good fit for my use, it seems that people are not familiar with this usage as they (incorrectly) believe this word is related to the word "teach".

Is there another word that can be used here that is more likely people will understand? For now I have just been trying to avoid using any word, but that causes some sentences to be difficult to read.

Two example sentences:

> [WORD] for this program is $3,900 (with a $150 early-bird discount if you register before December 31, 2020). This amount is divided between the registration fee ($750 through December 31st, $900 after that) which is due immediately upon registration, and the remaining [WORD] ($3,000) which may be paid completely by March 1, 2021, or in three monthly installments of $1,000 by March 1st, April 1st, and May 1st.

Comment: Cost for this program...   remaining balance...

Comment: *people are not familiar with this usage as they (incorrectly) believe this word is related to the word "teach".* The word [tuition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tuition) *does* mean 'teaching' and is also used to mean the *fee* for teaching.

Comment: @WeatherVane: More accurately, ***tuition*** is often used as shorthand for *tuition **fees*** (where "tuition" does indeed relate to tutors and teaching). But 
 "tuition" normally implies *academic* guidance / training (which I assume isn't much in evidence in a US "summer camp" context), so just plain ***fees*** looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**The fee**] for this program is $3,900 (with a $150 early-bird discount if you register before December 31, 2020). This amount is divided between the registration fee ($750 through December 31st, $900 after that) which is due immediately upon registration, and the remaining [**balance**] ($3,000) which may be paid completely by March 1, 2021, or in three monthly installments of $1,000 by March 1st, April 1st, and May 1st.

https://www.usasummercamp.com/faq/fees-payments/

Comment: I'm not sure `installment` is the correct word for the second one, since I use the same word later in the sentence to split that $3,000 into three installments too.

Comment: Okay, let's use Jim's suggestion, and say 'balance.'